# GraphQL/MongoDB: cannot delete database entry with the unique _id (although I am able to delete using other filters)

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I set up a delete API in my MERN stack project that works successfully in the GraphQL playground for other filters, but not when I try to filter by the uniquely generated _id that Mongo generates for every new entry.

In the GraphQL schema:

```
type Mutation {
 greetingDelete(_id: ID!): Boolean
}
```

The resolver function:

```
async function greetingDelete(_, { _id }){
    
    await db.collection('greetingMessages').deleteOne({ _id });
    return
}
```

In the GraphQL playground:

```
mutation {
  greetingDelete( _id: "6053c1a904224f22cc1c0dcf")
}
```

When I submit this in the GraphQL playground, I do not get any error messages, but the entry is not deleted. However, if I tweak the source code slightly (in the schema mutation type and in the resolver) so that the filter references any other property keys (instead of _id) in the entry object, then the API works, and an entry *can* be successfully deleted from the playground.

What's the reason for this? Is there a way I can delete by _id, or should I be deleting using a different property key?

Answer (score 0):

deleteOne({ _id }) expects _id to be ObjectId type.  Convert it to ObjectId should work.

```
import MongoDb from 'mongodb';

await db.collection('greetingMessages').deleteOne({ _id: MongoDb.ObjectId(_id) });
```